# QGIS - Disable ability to download plugins for unauthorized users?

Tags: qgis, plugins, disable

In QGIS desktop, is there a way to disable the ability for unauthorized users to download plugins? Is it possible to change the settings so that the "Manage and Install Plugins" menu item is not available?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! I haven't test it but if you block write access to QGIS plugin directory, it may be a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may configure `startup.py` file (cf related [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file) using or not the environment variable `PYQGIS_STARTUP`)

Within startup.py file, you can put the following:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

# Disable plugin install menu
action = iface.pluginMenu().actions()[0]
action.setDisabled(True)

# Or remove it (uncomment and restart QGIS to try)
# iface.pluginMenu().removeAction(action)
```

This solution is only hiding/disabling the menu. In fact, any advanced user will be able to bypass it but this recipe should be enough for most people.